# Zeit now deployment errors

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have just completed  the next.js tutorial and have created a simple app. I am now trying to deploy the app with Zeit Now, although when I type 'now' into the windows powershell I get an error: Error! EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Craig\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files'

I have to tried to google some solutions but have had no luck so far. Can anyone see from the error what I need to do to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Run your powershell as administrator and deploy the project like you normally would. Then you will have access to the directory.